# JSON Names from SpringFramework @Controller, @ResponseBody

Tags: json, spring

I've got a simple Spring Controller who's purpose is to return a RESTful JSON response of my entity objects.  Its returning  the data in standard camelCase names which match my entity.  However, I'd like the JSON names to match the database fields, which is simply TitleCase.  Is there a simple way to do this?  Below is a sample of the Controller and the JSON returned.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/Users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping(path="/List")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
            // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
            return userRepository.findAll();
        }
    }
```

Resulting JSON:

```
{"id":1,"userName":"SYSTEM","password":"xxxxx","firstName":"System","lastName":"System","phone":"XXX-XXX-XXXX","email":"system@test.com","reviewer":false,"admin":false}
```

Here's my User entity class:

```
package com.prs.business;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name="username")
    @JsonProperty("UserName")
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    @Column(name="isreviewer")
    private boolean reviewer;
    @Column(name="isadmin")
    private boolean admin;
    @Column(name="isactive")
    private boolean active;
    @Column(name="datecreated")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    private Timestamp dateCreated;

    public User() {
        userName = "";
        password = "";

    }

    public User(int id, String userName, String password, String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber,
            String email, boolean reviewer, boolean admin) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phoneNumber;
        this.email = email;
        this.reviewer = reviewer;
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public User(String un, String pw, String fn, String ln, String pn, String e, boolean m, boolean a) {
        setUserName(un);
        setPassword(pw);
        setFirstName(fn);
        setLastName(ln);
        setPhoneNumber(pn);
        setEmail(e);
        setReviewer(m);
        setAdmin(a);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phone = phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public boolean isReviewer() {
        return reviewer;
    }
    public void setReviewer(boolean inReviewer) {
        this.reviewer = inReviewer;
    }
    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return admin;
    }
    public void setAdmin(boolean inAdmin) {
        this.admin = inAdmin;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return admin;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean inActive) {
        this.admin = inActive;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", userName=" + userName + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", phoneNumber=" + phone + ", email=" + email + ", reviewer="
                + reviewer + ", admin=" + admin + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: check `@JsonProperty` annotation

Comment: You can use @JsonProperty("User Name") on top your getter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to enable pascal case for all JSON property names?

Put the following setting in your `application.properties`

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=UPPER_CAMEL_CASE
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  That looks incredibly simple.  I tried it on my userName field as below, but the result is the username field simply gets dropped from my JSON response all together.  No error message, no compile issues, just dropped.  When I added the annotation I imported it from fasterxml package.  Is that correct?  am I doing something else wrong?

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

Comment: (continued...)  My username field should be listed 2nd, between id and password, but just gets dropped.
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

     '@JsonProperty("UserName")
     private String userName;

    [{"id":1,"password":"xxxxx",

Comment: Yes, that is the correct package. As your using Spring, it should work out of the box. Can you update your question with your `User` class?

Comment: Thanks so much for responding quickly and continuing to help.  I've added my entity.

Comment: I want to confirm something: do you want your field names to be `PascalCase` or `Title Case`? Because you stated you want your fields to be title case, but in your `User` sample your annotation is pascal case.

Comment: First letter of each word capitalized, no space between.  I hadn't heard of this called Pascal Case though.  Good to know.

Comment: Updated answer. You can remove the @JsonProperty annotations.

Comment: I was adding the JsonProperty about to solve my problem of returning the wrong case for my field names.  For example, I want FirstName rather than firstName.  Is there a way to do this other than using JsonProperty?

Comment: Got it.  Sorry I missed that.  Just tried it out and it works.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

userRepository.findAll() will probably return a POJO, right?
In that pojo, before the getters or before the fields declaratin, you can add an annotion like

```
@JsonProperty("<hereYouWriteTheNameYouPrefer>")
private String userName;
```

or

```
private String userName;

@JsonProperty("<hereYouWriteTheNameYouPrefer>")
public String getUserName(){
    return userName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco.  I've tried your suggestion, similar to @Synch, on my username field.  The result is my field simply gets dropped from  my JSON response, no error message or anything.  Really strange.  I'm importing the Jackson JsonProperty, com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is really strange. I'll try to guess: do you have the class annotation ```@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)``` and your username is null?

Comment: I agree.. very strange. I'd at least have expected an error of some kind.  No, all my usernames are required and are all filled in.